# Prolog, Outputting a Variable After a Relation is Used

Tags: prolog

This is my first-day learning prolog and I would like to write a program that decides what shoes I should wear based on the weather and what kind of appointment I have at the office. The main "function" would be declared for example:

```
"go :- outfit(snow, 15, casual, F1), write(F1)."
```

Where snow is the weather, 15 is the temperature(not relevant now), and casual is the formality of the appointment. "write(F1)" will display the "output" so the variable F1 needs to be the result of said relation(s). Here are the rules for what shoes to wear:

```
%Rules for weather
rain(Weather) :- (Weather = 'rain').
snow(Weather) :- (Weather = 'snow').
nice(Weather) :- (Weather = 'nice').
clear(Weather) :- (Weather = 'clear').

%Rules for formality
formal(Appointment) :- (Appointment = 'formal').
semiformal(Appointment) :- (Appointment = 'semiformal').
casual(Appointment) :- (Appointment = 'casual').

%Rules for when to wear a type of footwear
dressShoes(Appointment) :- formal(Appointment).
boots(Appointment, Weather) :- not(formal(Appointment)), (rain(Weather);snow(Weather)).
sneakers(Appointment, Weather) :- not(formal(Appointment)), (nice(Weather);clear(Weather)).
```

This is where my issue is, I am not sure how to tie the last three relations to a single relation that fills the variable "F1" for my final "outfit" function. I am a C++ guy, so I would like to essentially place a string into F1 like "[sneakers]" or "[boots]" but this is part of my growing pains with prolog. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some misunderstandings about Prolog I guess. This kind of rule:

```
rule(Variable) :- (Variable = 'value').
```

You don't need to quote `'value'`, it is already an *atom*. Whatever book you are reading, look up atoms. It becomes:

```
rule(Variable) :- (Variable = value).
```

You don't need the extra parentheses in the rule definition. It becomes:

```
rule(Variable) :- Variable = value.
```

You don't need the explicit unification in the body. There is nothing else happening between the head and the body. So you don't need a variable, either. It becomes:

```
rule(value).
```

Applying this to your program, I get:

```
rain(rain).
snow(snow).
nice(nice).
clear(clear).

%Rules for formality
formal(formal).
semiformal(semiformal).
casual(casual).
```

Those rules say pretty much nothing ;-)

Your example at the very top:

```
go :- outfit(snow, 15, casual, F1), write(F1).
```

Does *exactly* the same as just calling `outfit(snow, 15, casual, F1)`. So what is the purpose of the "go" and the "write"? Skip them I guess.

The logic of your program: can you explain it without code? Your code is so unusual that I have to guess.

If you want to say, "If the appointment is formal, put on dress shoes", you could write it like this:

```
occasion_shoes(Occasion, Shoes) :-
    formality_occasion(Formality, Occasion),
    formality_shoes(Formality, Shoes).

formality_occasion(formal, evening_party).
formality_occasion(semi_formal, office).

formality_shoes(formal, dress_shoes).
```

Do you see what is going on? You match the occasion to the shoes. To do that, you look up the formality of the occasion in the table `formality_occasion/2` and then match it to the formality of the shoes in the `formality_shoes/2` table.

If you are struggling to model your problem, you can also read up on relational database design.

Comment: Yeah, that helped a lot. I'm gonna play around with what you told me. Thanks